# Broken -Bmac.CFBundleVersion option in javapackager

Tags: java, macos, deployment, version, javapackager

On macOS, the command-line option `-Bmac.CFBundleVersion=<value>` specified in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) of Oracle `javapackager` utility does not work.

I am using the following command to create the disk image `Application.app` from `Application.jar`:

```
javapackager \
  -deploy \
  -native image \
  -srcfiles Application.jar \
  -outdir dist \
  -outfile Application \
  -appclass Application \
  -BappVersion=2.0 \
  -Bmac.CFBundleVersion=2.0.0 \
  -BjvmOptions=-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
```

The popup window opened from the "About Application" item in the menu bar displays the following string:

```
Application

Version 2.0 (100)
```

instead of

```
Application

Version 2.0 (2.0.0)
```

When I check the generated `Application.app/Contents/Info.plist` file, I see that `javapackager` correctly read the command-line option `-BappVersion=2.0` to set the value of the key `CFBundleShortVersionString`, but failed to read the command-line option `-Bmac.CFBundleVersion=2.0.0` to set the value of the key `CFBundleVersion`:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>2.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>100</string>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, have you tested with the latest JDK 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version (update 25) of the Java SE Development Kit 8. I downloaded and installed the last version (update 121) from Oracle's website (jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg) and it solved the problem. Thank you @Nicolas Filotto.